# OR condition in regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I have table with even & odd row like this

```
<table id="overviewTable" class="dataTable labelValueTable">
<tr class="even">
  <td class="label">A</td>
<td>
<a href="#">A</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td class="label">A</td>
  <td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td class="label">A</td>
<td>C</td></tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td class="label">A</td>
<td>D</td></tr>
```

and I wrote pattern for it like this

```
@<tr class="(even|odd)">(.*?)<\/tr>@si
```

but it doesn't work.how can I fix this?

Comment: Works for me... what, specifically, doesn't work? https://regex101.com/r/dS8mW7/1

Comment: @Mofi : When I change regex to "@<tr class="(?:even|odd)">(.*?)<\/tr>@sgi" I see this warning and my array is empty preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably because 'g' is a) not on the [list of recognized modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and b) redundant with `preg_match_all`.